# List of lists vs single list memory usage in Python

Tags: python, list, memory

I have a bunch of numbers that I have to organize and am thinking of organizing in lists them by their semantic meaning.

> What is the overhead in terms of memory usage of organizing data as
>   a list of lists versus a single flat list in python?

I.e.

- `[[x1,y1,v1],[x2,y2,v2], ... , [xn,yn,vn]]`
- `[x1,y1,v1,x2,y2,v2, ... , xn,yn,vn]`

Comment: It's probably the same tiny overhead for any size of `list`.

Comment: How many is a bunch? And what are you storing as your xs, ys, and vs? http://www.valuedlessons.com/2008/10/blog-post.html seems to have measured the overhead of different python datastructures.

Comment: Each list has a tiny overhead. How many lists are in your list? Will you be doing lot's of append on them? What kind of searches will you do on them?

Answer (score -2):

There would be very, very little overhead. Organize your data in whichever way makes the most semantic sense, and don't worry about performance until it's actually a problem. In this case, it's highly unlikely that it would ever become an issue.

Comment: Can you cite some references and provide an explanation?